# How $_post in PHP works

Tags: php, jquery

I am passing variable from jquery to php, and trying to submit my form through submit button also, but my variable is not visible in $_POST['submit'].

I have an html page with a list where I am choosing more than one value and concatenating it with ':' and passing it to PHP. 
once I press the submit button on the form I want to insert that selected list in my database table.

Please, can someone explain.
**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form action="new_page.php" method="post">
    <select class= "sweet" name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
      <option>Chocolate</option>
      <option >Candy</option>
      <option>Taffy</option>
      <option>Caramel</option>
      <option>Fudge</option>
      <option>Cookie</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name ="submit" value ="submit"  />
    <script>
    $(function(){ 
        var s_type="";
        $('.sweet').click(function() {
            if(s_type.length){
                s_type+= " : " + $(this).val(); 
            }else{
                s_type+=  $(this).val();
            }
            $.post('new_page.php', 'sweet=' +s_type, function (response){
                alert(response);
            });

        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

**PHP Page  new_page.php**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['sweet'])){
       $filename = $_POST['sweet'];
   }
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
        if(isset($_POST['sweet'])){
            $filename = $_POST['sweet'];
            echo '*****profile   ' .$filename;
        }
        $id= 'A';
        $db =  new PDO("sqlite:test.db");
        $q1 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO test_sweet(id,sweets) values(?,?)');
        $q1->execute(array($id,$filename));           
   }
?>
```

Comment: you need to show your form html+jquery code of posting data along with this code

Comment: Submit is a button, and if you want to check, is there any information is set or not then better to check the form field values not submit button value.

Comment: jquery must send a post request

Comment: @Alive to Die updated my question.

Comment: Hi @jens my jquery is sending post request , but I am unale to understnd how to access the variable passed by query.

Comment: @Saroj, I just want to make a database insert on click of submit.

Comment: If you want to test `$_POST['submit']` then you have to add that to your parameters in the `'sweet=' +s_type` You are only posting `sweet` currently

Comment: You are completely missing the `<form>` tag, hence your submit button doesn't actually send a POST request.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am sorry i couldnt understand what you mean.

Comment: @ccKep I dont think he wants the form to do the submit. Its the ajax call that OP is trying to use

Comment: @ccKep, I am sorry about that I added the same `<form action="new_page.php" method="post">`  . But still getting the error.

Comment: There is really too much wrong in this code, I think you would be best served by looking at some tutorials or reading book on AJAX

Comment: @RiggsFolly If he wants the ajax to be submitted on the submit button - he should bind it to that, not the select-click.

Comment: @ccKep, The thing is I want to choose more than one item from list and want to concatenate that with a ':' thats why I did it on click and when I am done with all the options I am clicking the submit button, so that I can insert the whole concatenated string in database.

Comment: Your post in the jquery should look like this I beleive "$.post('new_page.php', { sweet: s_type }, function (response){"

Comment: @Blinkydamo, I tried to update the same,but its not making any difference.

Comment: I added an answer with code similar to yours, **although: If you just want multiple values in your select, make your select accept multiple values.. not this javascript workaround**. Eg: `<select multiple><option ...><option ...></select>`. People can then just ctrl-click multiple items, just like they're used to from their OS / everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'll add this remark here aswell:
**If you want multiple values from your `<select>` change it into `<select multiple>` and you're done, this JS is a rather unintuitive workaround.**
(Even moreso since you can't easily remove values you selected without reloading the whole page)

Might give this a try, mind you it's drycoded (untested):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="sweetForm">
      <select id="selSweets" name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Chocolate</option>
        <option >Candy</option>
        <option>Taffy</option>
        <option>Caramel</option>
        <option>Fudge</option>
        <option>Cookie</option>
      </select>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
      $(function() { 
        var sweets = [];
        $('#selSweets').change(function() {
          var val = $(this).val();
          if (sweets.indexOf(val) == -1) // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility for browser compatibility on indexOf()
            sweets.push(val);
        });

        $("#sweetForm").submit(function(e)
        {
          $.post(
            'new_page.php',
            {
              sweets: sweets
            },
            function(data, status, jqXHR)
            {
              console.log(data);
            }
          );
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working :-(

Comment: You won't have a `$_POST['submit']`, only `$_POST['sweets']` (containing an array of selected sweets - that's clear? Add `var_dump($_POST);` to the top of your PHP script to see what you're receiving.

Comment: I have updated php `<?php
   var_dump($_POST);
      if(isset($_POST['sweet'])){
          $filename = $_POST['sweet'];
          echo $filename;

          $id= 'A';
          $db =  new PDO("sqlite:c:/sqlite/test.db");
          $q1 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO test_sweet(id,sweets) values(?,?)');
          $q1->execute(array($id,$filename));        
      }
   ?>`   but now click on submit is not doing anything , not even an error.

Comment: For testing purposes, you could just change it to `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>`. What does the network tab of your browser show?

Comment: Thank you so much @ccKep for your time and effort  , I changed the approach and it worked this time.Instead of concatenating and passing throgh Jquery , I concated it in the PHP .